# How to print portion of the string from 'startswith' till 'endswith'

Tags: python, python-3.x, startswith, ends-with

I like to save portions of the original text file, which can be identified in between 'startswith' and 'endswith' strings, into a new text file.

Example: The input text file contains following lines:

```
...abc…
...starts with string...
...def...
...ends with string...
...ghi...

...jkl...
...starts with string...
...mno...
...ends with string...
...pqr...
```

I am interested to extract the following lines into output text file:

```
starts with string...def...ends with string
starts with string...mno...ends with string
```

My following code returns empty list [ ]. Please help correct my code.

```
with open('file_in.txt','r') as fi:
    id = []
    for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("start with string"):
            if ln.endswith("ends with string"):
                id.append(ln[:])
                with open(file_out.txt, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fo:
                    fo.write (",".join(id))
print(id)
```

I expect the file.out.txt to contain, all strings which start with the "start with string" and end with the "ends with string".

Comment: Thanks for the update with test data. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544826/3767239) accordingly, please check whether it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of each line there is a character to tell the computer to show a new row. I am assuming here that  "start with string" and "ends with string" are on the same line. If this is not the case add --"id.append(ln[:])"-- directly below the first if statement.

Try

```
ln.endswith("ends with string"+'\n' )
```

or

```
ln.endswith("ends with string"+'\n' +'\r')
```

```
with open('C:\\Py\\testing.txt','r') as fi:
    id = []
    x = 0
    copy_line = False
    for ln in fi:
        if "starts with string" in ln:
            copy_line = True
        if copy_line:
            id.append ( ln[:] )
        if "ends with string" in ln :
            copy_line = False

    with open ('C:\\Py\\testing_out.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8' ) as fo:
        fo.write (",".join(id))

print(id)
```

Comment: Still returns empty list [ ].  I will try some variations an update. Thanks.

Comment: I have another strategy to use a boolean operator. See the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

[`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) return True or False rather than a position you can use to slice your string. Try [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) or [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) instead. For example:

```
start = 'starts with string'
end = 'ends with string'
s = '...abc… ...starts with string... ...def... ...ends with string... ...ghi...'

sub = s[s.find(start):s.find(end) + len(end)]
print(sub)
# starts with string... ...def... ...ends with string
```

You will need to add a bit of checking in your loop to see if the start and end strings exist because `find` will return -1 if there is no match and this would result in some unintended slicing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate variable to indicate whether the current line is part of an interesting section and toggle this variable based on start and stop markers. Then you can also turn this function into a generator:

```
def extract(fh, start, stop):
    sub = False
    for line in fh:
        sub |= start in line
        if sub:
            yield line
            sub ^= stop in line

with open('test.txt') as fh:
    print(''.join(extract(fh, 'starts with string', 'ends with string')))
```

In Python 3.8 you can use [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
import itertools as it

def extract(fh, start, stop):
    while any(start in (line := x) for x in fh):
        yield line
        yield from it.takewhile(lambda x: stop not in x, ((line := y) for y in fh))
        yield line

with open('test.txt') as fh:
    print(''.join(extract(fh, 'starts with string', 'ends with string')))
```

### Variation: Excluding start and stop markers

In case start and stop markers are to be excluded from the output, we can again use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools as it

def extract(fh, start, stop):
    while any(start in x for x in fh):
        yield from it.takewhile(lambda x: stop not in x, fh)

with open('test.txt') as fh:
    print(''.join(extract(fh, 'starts with string', 'ends with string')))
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've updated my answer to meet the OP's requirements (include start and stop markers in the output), also with an example usage.

Comment: @a_guest:  Using 'assignment expressions':  following error:

>File "<ipython-input-3-ad96b09294e9>", line 4
    while any(start in (line := x) for x in fh):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @anatta As mentioned, assignment expressions were introduced in Python 3.8 which is currently only available as [alpha version](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380a3/).

Comment: @a_guest:  Missed it.  I will update to 3.8 alpha, and try.  Thanks.